# Php array from DB Result

Tags: php, arrays

How can i convert result from Database to somehow multidimensional array?
Example:
 Records of users in DB
     I tried coding something like this(Not code but illustration):
   1 user => `John Adams`
   2 users => `Peter Greenman and John Adams`
   3 users => `Sarah Josh,Peter Greenman and John Adams`
  50 users => `Sarah Josh,Peter Greenman and 48 others`.
    How can i display records with the number of users in the DB just like i stated above
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> declare array outside loop and store database value inside loop

```
$names = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){$names[]= database row;}
print_r($name);
```